# Format Data using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am having data in below format in a file

```
Section : A1234,
Name : ABCBDEDF,
Medium : English ,
Age : No,   
Name : Reporting,
Age : No
Section : XYSZA,
Name : Work,
Age : YES
```

I am trying to achieve data in below format :--

```
Section : A1234,Name : ABCBDEDF,Age : No
Section : A1234,Name : Reporting,Age : No
Section : XYSZA,Name : Work,Age : YES
```

I tried few sed and awk statements to but I am able to merge only all rows together.

`awk '{key=$0; getline; print key "" $0;}' test.txt`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't there a line with `Section` missing or is that intended?

Comment: It is intended .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '/Section/{val1=$0;next} /Name/{val2=$0;next} /Age/{sub(/,/,"");print val1 val2 $0;}'   Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** Since OP told OP requires everything between `Section` and `flag` strings then following may help in same.

```
awk '/Age/ && flag{sub(/,/,"");print val1  $0;val1=flag="";next} /Section/{val1=$0;flag=1;next} flag{val1=val1  $0;}'  Input_file
```

If you want to have everything between strings `section` and `flag` and we have to make sure each group should have `section` in it else it will NOT print it.

Comment: It works great . I have one question so if more rows gets added between Name and Age I will have to just keep adding those in the query and print it right ?

Comment: @AnandAbhay, no if more rows coming in between Name and Age above code will not pick it. Since you haven't shown us sample for it. Do you want to have everything between Name and Age strings?

Comment: Yes . That would be great as it will kill the dependency of fixed rows.

Comment: @AnandAbhay, please try my EDIT code now and let me know if that helps you.

Comment: Hi .. what it does is .. It adds Medium : English , to all line  in that section . I have modified the input file in question .

Comment: So you mean if a group doesn't have `section` in it, it should skip it right? Please don't change requirements frequently in your questions.

Comment: Hi.. I didnt work. I will use the previous answer and see what can be done . Thank you ..

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
while IFS=" ," read -r x foo y; do 
  [[ $x == "Section" ]] && s="$y"
  [[ $x == "Name" ]] && n="$y"
  [[ $x == "Age" ]] && a="$y" && echo "Section : $s,Name : $n,Age : $a"
done < file
```

Output:

```
Section : A1234,Name : ABCBDEDF,Age : No
Section : A1234,Name : Reporting,Age : No
Section : XYSZA,Name : Work,Age : YES
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I consider the most likely input format, a section can have *multiple* name/age pairs following it.

If that's the case then you just need to store the last section seen, and output it with the name and age.

We can just store the most recently seen section and name and use that along with each age. That will also allow you to skip names in the input file but, if they're there, it will not have an effect.

That means that this should do the trick:

```
awk  '/^Section/{sec=$0}/^Name/{nm=$0}/^Age/{print sec""nm""$0}'
```

The following transcript shows it in action:

```
printf 'Section : A1234,\nName : ABCBDEDF,\nAge : No,\nName : Reporting,\nAge : No\nSection : XYSZA,\nName : Work,\nAge : YES\n' | awk  '/^Section/{sec=$0}/^Name/{nm=$0}/^Age/{print sec""nm""$0}'
```

with the output being, as you requested:

```
Section : A1234,Name : ABCBDEDF,Age : No,
Section : A1234,Name : Reporting,Age : No
Section : XYSZA,Name : Work,Age : YES
```

Note that the first line has a comma at the end, this is caused by that being in your input data. If you want it stripped out, that will add another minor complication to the code. For now, I'll just assume either your input data is incorrect or you want it echoed as-is.

Comment: Thanks . I have same request to you also, what if there are more lines between Name and Age in one section but less in other. It wont work in that condition right ?

Comment: @AnandAbhay, i think it still works. it's better that you need test it before asking.

Comment: @Anand, you should have made that clear in the question, we're not mind readers :-) This answer is tailored to your stated requirements with the assumption I made, detailed in the answer. If you wish to elaborate on the requirements, that's probably done in a different question.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried something with your modified input. Check if below works

```
awk '/^Section/{s=$0}
     /^Name/ && match(p,/^Age/){$0=sprintf("%s%s%s",s,ORS,$0)}
     {print;p=$0}' file_name | sed ':a;/Age/!{N;s/\n//g;ba}'
```

**Output(Вывод)**

```
Section : A1234,Name : ABCBDEDF,Medium : English ,Age : No,   
Section : A1234,Name : Reporting,Age : No
Section : XYSZA,Name : Work,Age : YES
```

---

<sup>**Note(Заметка)** : The `awk` part does the preprocessing here to add `Section` in missing places and `sed` prints the output in required format.</sup>

Comment: I created a new file Section : ANC
Name : ABCDER
Name : XTYRERY
Name : ABCDFG and now when I try to run ` awk '/^Section/{s=$0} /^Name/ && match(p,/^Name/){$0=sprintf("%s%s%s",s,ORS,$0)} {print;p=$0}' 1.txt | sed ':a;/Name/!{N;s/\n//g;ba}' > 1_tmp.txt` .. it doesnt work. Any  specific place I am going wrong .

Comment: @AnandAbhay Put the new file in question. Putting it in a comment doesn't make any sense.